# Why does entityManager.clear() fails my tests due to different date values even though I am not changing any of them?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

So I am running a @DataJpaTest and in my setUp function, I do entityManager.clear() which ends up detaching the books objects from the persistence context. But the following test ends up failing with the error.

Error when comparing the whole Book entity ->

```
BookRepositoryTest > doSomething() FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <Book(id=6, title=Pride and Prejudice, price=16.99, quantity=12, author=Jane Austen, ISBN=890-1234567890, genre=Romance, publishDate=1813-01-28)> but was: <Book(id=6, title=Pride and Prejudice, price=16.99, quantity=12, author=Jane Austen, ISBN=890-1234567890, genre=Romance, publishDate=1813-01-27)>
        at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:151)
        at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.buildAndThrow(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:132)
        at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.failNotEqual(AssertEquals.java:197)
        at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:182)
        at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:177)
        at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:1145)
        at app//library.backend.api.BookRepositoryTest.doSomething(BookRepositoryTest.java:55)
```

Error when only comparing the dates ->

```
BookRepositoryTest > doSomething() FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: The dates do not match ==> expected: <1813-01-28> but was: <1813-01-27>
        at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:151)
        at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.buildAndThrow(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:132)
        at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.failNotEqual(AssertEquals.java:197)
        at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:182)
        at app//org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:1156)
        at app//library.backend.api.BookRepositoryTest.doSomething(BookRepositoryTest.java:55)
```

But the moment I comment out the entityManager.clear() line, the tests pass.
Anyone has any idea why this happens? I am not making any changes to any of the books so why are the dates being changed when reading from the db?

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test"})
public class BookRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    
    @Value("classpath:books.json")
    Resource booksJson;

    List<Book> books;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception{
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        books = mapper.readValue(booksJson.getInputStream(),
                            new TypeReference<List<Book>>(){});
        books.forEach(entityManager::persistAndFlush);
        entityManager.clear();
    }

    @Test
    void doSomething(){
        List<Book> firstSixBooks = bookRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0,6)).toList();
        assertEquals(6, firstSixBooks.size());
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++){
            assertEquals(books.get(j).getPublishDate(), firstSixBooks.get(j).getPublishDate());
        }
    }

}
```

Any help or advices are appreciated!

I am expecting for the tests to pass even with entityManager.clear() and it is ends up failing, I want to know why out of curiosity.

Comment: Does your findAll() method include an order by clause? Can you share the first couple of records from books.json? Are the dates in bookouts.json in the same timezone as the machine running the tests?

Comment: Does your Book class override equals()?

Answer (score 0):

> I am expecting for the tests to pass even with entityManager.clear() and it is ends up failing, I want to know why out of curiosity.

When you persist an entity object using an `EntityManager`, that object itself becomes persistent.  Among other things, it means that that object is cached by the `EntityManager`.  That's perhaps the main thing that distingishes a persistent entity from a detached one.

When an `EntityManager` is asked for an entity that it already has cached, it provides the cached instance itself, not a copy.  This is what happens in your test when you do not detach the entities.  In this case, you are testing whether objects are `equals()` themselves, which is true of any `Object` that does not have a perverse, non-conforming `equals(Object)` method.  It is in no way surprising, then, that the `equals()` tests pass.

But if you *do* detach the entities, by `clear()`ing the `EntityManager`, for example, then it must instantiate new ones when you request them.  In this case, you compare distinct objects with equal property values.  These will compare equal if and only if you have given the entity class an `equals(Object)` method that produces that result.  The one inherited from `Object` will not produce that result.

Especially for entities, it's debatable whether you should equip classes with such an `equals()` method.  If you decide to do, however, then you should make sure to implement a compatible `hashCode()` method as well.

IMO, your test fixture *should* clear the `EntityManager`.  If you decide to give the `Book` class an `equals()` method corresponding to the conditions you want to test then that should be sufficient to make your existing test pass.  Otherwise, you should modify the test so that it evaluates whatever sense of equality you want to check.  For example, that might mean comparing one or more individual fields.

Comment: No, the main problem is with the date's not matching. Even if I don't try to check for equality for the whole object, and just check if ``assertEquals(books.get(j).getPublishDate(), firstSixBooks.get(j).getPublishDate());`` is equal, the dates don't match. I ``clear()`` the entityManager because I want the ``findAll`` request to go to the db instead of just fetching the managed objects in persistent context, but the fact that the assertion isn't true shows that the date is getting stored incorrectly in the database, right?

Comment: Well, @Made_In_Heaven, I'd characterize that more as a "not exactly".  I've explained why your tests do pass when you don't clear the `EntityManager`.  As far as I know, I might also have explained why the original version of your test failed -- nothing in the question is inconsistent with my explanation.  It's unclear why you are reading back a different date from the DB than was stored on the original entity, but the question doesn't contain any of the information that should inform that analysis, such as the entity and table definitions.

Comment: Well, the publishDate is ``LocalDate``. I understand why my tests pass when I don't do ``clear()``. Now, since I am only comparing dates, they should match. I just thought of instead of using H2, I use a mysql db instead, and guess what, the tests pass irrespective of the fact whether ``clear()`` is being called or not. That must mean it has to do with how H2 is parsing/storing localdate.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the doSomething() test method to compare the dates as strings by calling toString() on the LocalDate objects. This modification allows you to compare the date values themselves rather than their object references, which can help ensure consistent results in your tests

```
@Test
void doSomething(){
    List<Book> firstSixBooks = bookRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0,6)).toList();
    assertEquals(6, firstSixBooks.size());
    for(int j=0; j<6; j++){
        // Compare dates as strings to avoid object reference issues
        assertEquals(books.get(j).getPublishDate().toString(), firstSixBooks.get(j).getPublishDate().toString());
    }
}
```